# Combining two QT Dialog Windows

Tags: qt, qt5

As you can see from the title I'm trying to combine actions between two dialog windows. In particular I have such type of DialogWindow (Connection_Database.ui):
[image]

As you can see from the imagine above, there are the two buttons "Edit". With these two buttons I want to edit the corresponding label on their left side. So pushing "Edit" opens other dialog window (edit.ui):

[image]

lineEdit in the initial dialog should change it's value to a new value from second Dialog.

What sort of design should I use to achieve this?

Comment: That is unnecessarily complicated and ugly. Why don't you simply disable both `QLineEdit` fields and enable the appropriate one when the user clicks on `Edit`: `lineEditServerName->setEnabled(false)`;

Comment: @W.K.S the two lines on the first pictures are lables, that by default display some informations by reading from a .ini file with the button LOAD SETTINGS. But I want the possibility to change the values clicking on edit and save these new values by clicking on SAVE SETTINGS. So is important for me to respect the procedure that I specify. Anyway I didn't understood your suggests....

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having? You could just have your `Edit` dialog return a `QString`.

Comment: @thuga I can return a value Qstring from the Edit dialog? Sorry but I don't knoe how...can you explain me?

Comment: Classis OOP questions of beginners. You need to create some methods in your dialogs for gettings data.

Comment: Add a function that returns a `QString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample (pseudocode), based on comments:

```
class d1 // your first dialog
{
  void setText( QString text )
  {
    ui->text1->setText( text );
  }
};

class d2 // your second dialog
{
  QString getText() const
  {
    return ui->bigtextfield->text();
  }
};

d1 diag1;
d2 diag2;

void DataTransfer( d1& _d1, d2& _d2 ) .
{
  _d1.setText( _d2.getText() );  // Somewhere in your app
}
```